# Oracle performance question

Tags: oracle

I'm wondering if you have a table that contains 24 million record, how does that impact performance (does each insert/update/delete) take significantly longer to go through?

This is our Audit table, so when we make change changes in other tables we log then on to the Audit tale, does it also take significantly longer to carry out these update as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is "it depends", of course...

But as far as I get, your concern is in how Audit table affects performance of queries (on other tables) when Audit table grows.

Probably you only insert into your Audit table. Insert time doesn't depend on amount of data already in table. So, no matter how big Audit table is, it should affect performance equally (given that database design isn't incredibly bad).

Of course, select or delete on Audit table itseft *can* take longer when the table grows.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question as "does a large Oracle table take longer for IUD operations", generally speaking the answer is no.  I think the most impact on the insert/update/delete operations will be felt from the indexes present on this table (more indexes = slower performance for these operations).

However, if your auditing logic needs to look up existing rows in the audit table for procedural logic in some manner that doesn't use primary or unique keys, then there will be a performance impact with a large table.

Comment: Why ? Do you mean {delete all from table (with 10.000) }will take same time as {delete all from table (with 10.000.000) }     >"generally speaking the answer is no"< you are absolutely WRONG!

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that come into play in regards to how fast an insert/update/delete occurs.  For example, how many indexes are on the table?  If a table has many indexes and you insert/update the table, it can cause the operation to take longer. How is the data stored in the physical structures of the database (i.e. the tablespaces if you're using Oracle, for example)?  Are your indexes and data on separate disks, which can help speed up I/O?

Obviously, if you are writing out audit records then it can affect performance. But in a well-tuned database, it shouldn't be slowing it down enough to where you notice.

The approach I use for audit tables is to use triggers on the main tables and these triggers write out the audit records.  But from a performance standpoint, it really depends on a lot of factors as to how fast the updates to your main tables will run.

I would recommend looking at the explain plan output for one of your slow updates if you are using Oracle (other DBs usually have such tools as well, google can help here). You can then see what plan the optimizer is generating and diagnose where the problems could be.  You could potentially get a DBA to assist you as well to help figure out what's causing the slowness.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect performance will be more related to contention than table size. Generally inserts happen at the 'end' of the table. Sessions inserting into that table have to take a latch on the block while they are writing records to it. During that time other sessions may have to wait for that block (which is where you may see busy buffer wait events).

But really you need to look at the SQLs in question and see what they are waiting on, and whether they are contributing significantly to an unacceptable level of performance. Then determine a course of action based on the specific wait events that are causing the problem.

Check out anything from Cary Milsap on performance tuning

Answer (score 0):

The impact of table size is different for INSERT,DELETE AND UPDATE operation

Insert statement is not impacted much by table size as when we Insert data into table it will add to the next data block available.If there are Indexes on that particular table then Oracle has to search for particular data block before inserting data in that block ,which require search operation that need time.

Delete and Update statements are impacted by Table size as more the data more time is require to search for the particular row to Delete and Update operation